# Why this regular expression doesn't match this?

Tags: java, regex

I'm using the following regular expression (in java) to get the id, tittle and the year from a movie of a certain actor in IMDB.

```
/title/tt(\\d+)/\"\\s+itemprop=\"performerIn\"\\s*>\\s*(([\\(|\\)|&#\\d+;|\\w|!|/|:|-|.|,| ]+) \\(\\d\\d\\d\\d\\))</a>
```

(The most important part of the regex is what is after the "performerIn") 
I ran into trouble with [this](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0249291/) page to get the title "Star Wars: Episode III - Revenge of the Sith (2005)". It doesn't match. What is happening?

Comment: Can you cut it down to a minimal regex and minimal input string that together demonstrate the problem?

Comment: Please show us an example string you try to match against. Btw, never parse HTML with Regex.

Comment: Show how you use the regex also.  (`Pattern.compile` or whatever.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The character `-` is a **special character** inside a bracket expression, which denotes a *range*. For example, `[A-Z]` matches the range of characters from `A` to `Z`, ***not*** the characters `A`, `-`, and `Z`.

Thus, if you want to capture it, as in `Episode III - Escape of the Sith`, you need to escape it using `\\-`:

```
/title/tt(\\d+)/\"\\s+itemprop=\"performerIn\"\\s*>\\s*(([\\(|\\)|&#\\d+;|\\w|!|/|:|\\-|.|,| ]+) \\(\\d\\d\\d\\d\\))</a>
```

Also, when using a bracket expression, you don't need to use a pipe (`|`). That's the whole point of the bracket expression. So, instead of using `[,|:| ]` to match `,`, `:`, and a whitespace, use `[,: ] instead.`[,|:| ]`will match all those characters **AND** the pipe character itself, since inside a bracket expression, with the exception of`-`and`^` at the beginning, *everything* is matched as a **literal**.